# Can't assign a swift file to the second view

Tags: ios, swift, view

I created a second view and when I wanted to assign a new swift file as it's class, it didn't do it. Is this a bug?

It did not automatically complete while typing and I cannot define the contents of the view2 in the SecondViewController file.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the type SecondViewController inherit from? Should be UIViewController in its superclass chain.